# run iphone using Xcode on mac virtual machine

Tags: ios, iphone, ubuntu, usb, vmware

I'm using mac High Sierra on a virtual machine on ubuntu and I have a problem when I connect 'iPhone' to run on it instead of simulator it doesn't appear in Xcode

Comment: And iTunes are working on that Mac?

Comment: How can I know if iTunes working or not?

Comment: Your iTunes should be able to connect to the iPhone.

Comment: please I need more clarification. iphone appears on ubuntu but don't appear on mac